# Existential introduction in proof of $x \in B \setminus (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \rightarrow x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (B \setminus A_i)$ allowed?

Tags: logic, set-theory

**Theorem.**

Let $B$ be a set, $\{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ an indexed family, and $I ≠ \emptyset.$ Then

$x \in B \setminus (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \rightarrow x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (B \setminus A_i)$.

**Proof.**

$x \in B \setminus (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$ is equivalent to $x \in B \land x \notin (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i)$, which is equivalent to $x \in B \land \exists i \in I (x \notin A_i)$. Now let $i = i_0$. Then we have $x \in B \land x \notin A_{i_0}$. Applying existential introduction we then get $\exists i \in I (x \in B \land x \notin A_i)$, which in turn is equivalent to $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} (B \setminus A_i)$.

I'm interested in whether the existential introduction at the end and the last equivalence are correct.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: This seems to hinge around the prenex formula $$(\exists k ~ Y \land X_k) \equiv (Y \land \exists k ~ X_k)$$

Comment: Yes.It is correct.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i_0\in I$ and the statement $\varphi(i_0)$ is true, then certainly $(\exists i\in I)\,\, \varphi(i)$ is true.

I would have gone from $x \in B \land x \notin A_{i_0}$ to $x\in B\smallsetminus A_{i_0}$ and then to $(\exists i\in I)\,\, x\in B\smallsetminus A_i,$ and from there to $\displaystyle x\in\bigcup_{i\in I} (B\smallsetminus A_i),$

or else from $(\exists i \in I) \, (x \in B \land x \notin A_i)$ to $(\exists i\in I)\,(x\in B\smallsetminus A_i)$  and then to $\displaystyle x\in\bigcup_{i\in I} (B\smallsetminus A_i).$

I.e. when proving something so fundamental, be explicit about small steps.